# Connect to redis from another container in docker

Tags: python, redis, docker, tornado

I have app, that used Tornado and [tornado-redis](https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis). [image "app" in `docker images`]
I start redis:

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis
```

Then I want to link my app with redis:

```
docker run --name some-app --link some-redis:redis app
```

And I have error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 41, in <module>
    c.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornadoredis/client.py", line 333
, in connect
    self.connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornadoredis/connection.py", line
 79, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(str(e))
tornadoredis.exceptions.ConnectionError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have tested my code with local tornado and redis, and it works. The problem in

```
c = tornadoredis.Client()
c.connect()
```

Why my app cant connet to redis-container? How to fix that? I use standart port 6379.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post `docker logs some-redis` and `docker ports some-redis` or connect inside with `docker exec -it container_id bash` and check with `lsof -i:5555` (if the Redis port is 5555) and `netstat -an` and any debugging tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tornadoredis` attempts to use redis on `localhost`.  (See source [here](https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis/blob/6601788151b34940a1553b4e69a91b0d81bf82de/tornadoredis/client.py#L226))

So you need to inform `tornadoredis` where redis is running (since to the docker image it is not running on `localhost`).

For example:

```
c = tornadoredis.Client(host="<hostname>")
c.connect()
```

In your specific case, substitute `"redis"` for `"<hostname>"`.

Comment: I know about host, but I forgot about host "redis". Thanks!